# Update value of record which contains long query or large value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to update a value in table's record , which contains a complex as shown in the image. I need to change the complex query in that cell and update it in the table. Any help is appreciated.

The length of the complex query will be 13000 characters approximately.

[image]

Comment: *I need to change the complex query in that cell and update it in the table.* What change you need to make ? and Update in which table ?

Comment: Post the sample data in table format as text instead of image. For the sake of simplicity you can remove the columns that are not necessary for this problem

Comment: @prdp : I need to update "SearchQuery" column value in the same table.

Below is an example : 

SearchQuery old value : `select ID from table_1`
update to : `select ID,name from table_2`

Comment: @SaiKanthK ok have you tried to `UPDATE` are you having any specific issues, can you please state that. If you are getting any error, then please post the `error message` along with the query

Answer (score 0):

Use the following request, make sure you replace `[dbo].[myTable]` with the right schema/table.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[myTable]
SET [SearchQuery] = 'SELECT ID,name FROM table_2'
WHERE [SearchQuery] = 'select ID from table_1';
```

Comment: The above given query is an example. The actual query in my database is approximately 13000 chars and can't risk updating that value just by enclosing it single quotes because the query i have contains "single quote" symbol in it.

Comment: Just `REPLACE(string,'''','''''')` all your strings when you extract data to be updated.